# Parsing address information from pyusps

Tags: python, django, api

I'm working with Pyusps(Python USPS Api) to verify if an address actually exist. I've created a form to capture the data; I am having a hard time receiving the data back from the api and displaying it on the following page. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

```
#views.py

def address(args):
    address = AddressForm['street']

def city(args):
    city = AddressForm['city']

def state(args):
    state = AddressForm['state']

def zip5(args):
    zip5 = AddressForm['zip_code']


def address_view(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AddressForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        try:
            from pyusps import address_information
            addr = dict([
                ('address', {'address': address}),
                ('city', {'city': city}),
                ('state', {'state': state}),
                ('zip5', {'zip_code': zip5}),
            ])
            address_information.verify('API_ID', addr)
            a = dict([
                ('address', '6406 IVY LN'),
                ('city', 'GREENBELT'),
                ('state', 'MD'),
                ('zip5', '20770'),
                ('zip4', '1441'),
                ])
            c = {'form': a}
            return render_to_response('address_change.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        except ValueError:
            pass

else:
    form = AddressForm()
c = {'form': form}
return render_to_response('address_change.html', c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

#models.py
class Address(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
street = models.CharField(max_length=50)
city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=50)


# Pyusps API Documentation
from pyusps import address_information

 addr = dict([
 ('address', '6406 Ivy Lane'),
 ('city', 'Greenbelt'),
 ('state', 'MD'),
 ])
 address_information.verify('foo_id', addr)
  dict([
('address', '6406 IVY LN'),
('city', 'GREENBELT'),
('state', 'MD'),
('zip5', '20770'),
('zip4', '1441'),
])
```

Comment: can you be more specific? which part of your code is malfunctioning? what debug steps have you tried?

Comment: Newb here(I'm sure it's painfully obvious). I'm getting a type error(Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'dict') going to the next page. I converted the variables into unicode but it's still not working.

Comment: at what line did you get this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think I see your problem, this:

```
addr = dict([
                ('address', {'address': address}),
                ('city', {'city': city}),
                ('state', {'state': state}),
                ('zip5', {'zip_code': zip5}),
            ])
```

should be:

```
addr = dict([
                ('address', address),
                ('city', city),
                ('state', state),
                ('zip5', zip5),
            ])
```

Comment: although I'm a little confused by your code... why are you querying for an address, and then setting `a =` to a hardcoded address and rendering that?

Comment: Great point. I just changed that but I'm still getting a type error. I can run query in the shell and get responses back. I just don't know how to do it with form data.

Comment: it would be much easier to find the bug if you could provide which line the type error is occuring

Comment: Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'function'
Exception Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyusps/address_information.py in _create_xml, line 152

Comment: This is the function at 152 address_2_el = etree.Element('Address2')
        address_2_el.text = address
        address_el.append(address_2_el)

Comment: -_- look it would appear that your error is happening outside of what you have posted, please edit your original post or post a new question